# Hash key via Bootcamp on Macbook pro

Tags: laptop, keyboard, macbook, boot-camp

I have a Macbook Pro and installed on this is Windows via Bootcamp. Now I do a lot of programming and I can't find the hash key! Am I missing an obvious shortcut or is there a way to change the shortcuts on Windows in order to map hash to a key (alt 3, ala the Mac)

Comment: It may be worth noting that you're using a British English keyboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. This requires Bootcamp drivers are installed.

Answer (score 2):

It's the RH ALT key + 3 for # on my MBA under Win8.1 Bootcamp

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that I'm also programming on Windows on a Macbook, and I find AutoHotKey completely invaluable for programming shortcuts.

Quick example, if I press /' or '/ it actually gives me /* and */ which is great for commenting stuff out.

You could use AHK to setup another key to give you a # symbol.

Answer (score 0):

### Low-tech solution when nothing else will work...

Select below and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C

> #

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+V in your code window :)